# Two-way Animation with @keyframes

Tags: css, animation

I was creating a custom photo gallery, and suddenly faced this problem. If you create a @keyframes animation it can't be played the reverse way.

For example: You have an animation, which enlarges the square through scale(). If you hover it the square smoothly enlarges, but if you move the mouse out, your square will bounce back without animation.

Is there a way to reverse the animation on the back route? Transitions aren't working properly in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enlarge and image, you don't need to make an animation using @keyframes. you just make the image scales when hovering over it and make it scales slowly using CSS transition, for example:

```
   img:hover {
       transform: scale(2);
   }

   img {
       transition: all 1s;
   }
```

Comment: Square was an example. I have more complicated case. And, as I said, I don't need the transition.

Comment: I don't really know what situation you are exactly facing. But, there is a CSS property called **animation-direction**, it can accept **reverse** as value. I hope you can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .image{
        margin:400px;
        padding-top:5px;
        overflow:hidden;
        transition-duration:0.9s;
        transition-property:transform;
        }
.image:hover{
       transform:scale(2.5);
    }
```

---

```
<img class="image" src="download.jpg" alt="a" />
```